# RT-AC88U bandwidth limiter affect device that's not in the list

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth

I set an Android phone to have a bandwidth limit of up\down 10Mbps in Asus RT-AC88U.

Apparently this setting affect the bandwidth of a wired connected laptop.

The laptop is not even in the bandwidth limit list.

I have 1 Gbps Internet connection speed.

Before setting, laptop speed test is around 800 - 900Mbps.

After setting, laptop speed test is around 300 - 500Mbps.

Remove setting, laptop speed test is around 800 - 900Mbps.

I turn the router off then on, same result.

Why is that?